# Convertible tablet/laptop for multimedia/light gaming

Tags: laptop, tablet

I'm looking for a laptop/tablet with the following abilities & specifications:

- Ability to play lower-intensity games like *Civilization V* and *Planetary Annihilation* (confirmation from someone who has actually played those game (s) on that particular model is a bonus)
- Detachable (e.g. MS Surface Book) or folding keyboard (e.g. Lenovo Yoga). Full keyboard is a plus, but if someone makes a convincing case for one with a keyboard like the Surface Pro, I'd consider it
- Minimum of 11" screen (12"+ preferred), minimum of Full HD, prefer 1440p-ish
- Good battery life (5+ hours minimum)
- Microsoft Windows OS (full edition, not Windows 8 RT)
- Full size Solid state drive, minimum capacity of 128GB, prefer 256+
- Cost of $600-800 preferred, max of $1000

Not looking for a high-end 'gaming' tablet, just one that will play videos and lower intensity games reasonably well with a nice screen and good battery life. DisplayPort output is a plus but not required. Not particular to any hardware manufacturer, but it cannot be Android-based or an Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/yoga-laptop-series/yoga-3-pro-laptop/) will be perfect for you. It only costs $699.99. Features it has:

- 3200 x 1800 display
- 13.3 inch screen
- Intel Core M CPU
- 256/512GB SSD
- Good battery life
- Backlit keyboard
- 8GB of RAM

Another device that fits your price range is the [HP Spectre x360](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/Laptops/hp-spectre-x360---13-4110dx-%28energy-star%29). This is slightly more at $799.99 ($100 more than the Yoga 3 Pro). This is the major differences between this and the Yoga 3 Pro:

- Lower resolution screen (1080p)
- Better CPU (5th Gen Core i5)

Comment: Is this the best in the price range that meets the requirements? Or the only one?

Comment: @SSumner Updated with another laptop.